# Is there some method or an easy way so that I can return a hash that includes only the given keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I am looking for a method which is the opposite of [`except`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Hash/except) for hashes ([`except` documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Hash/except)), probably an `only` method. Is there some method or an easy way so that I can return a hash that includes *only* the given keys?

```
# Example, 'only' method as opposite to the 'except'
@person.update_attributes(params[:person].only(:name, :surname))
```

Comment: See also [Slicing Params Hash for Specific Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652976/slicing-params-hash-for-specific-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice), which will return a hash with only the given keys.

Comment: @GorrillaMcD - The Ruby on Rails team should continue to use the "common" `except/only` pair instead of `except/slice`! It can confuse a lot of people.

Comment: I tried googling for confirmation on this, but couldn't find anything. However, I think "only" is already used elsewhere in Ruby on Rails, so they had to pick a different name for the method.