# Ruby with Sequel and Sinatra: form parameter passing

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am new to Ruby and Sinatra. I am attempting to pass parameters from an HTML form and insert them into a PostgreSQL database (on Heroku) with Sequel.

The connection to the database works because I have succeeded with this code block

```
DB = Sequel.connect(connection_ credentials)

insert_ds = DB["INSERT INTO users (email_address, username, password) VALUES ('email@email.com', 'my_username', 'my_password')"]
insert_ds.insert
```

This works fine, but I cannot insert data from an HTML form. The data is not being passed.

So, for example, this does not work

```
@email_address = params[:email_address]
@username = params[:username]
@password = params[:password]

insert_ds = DB["INSERT INTO users (email_address, username, password) VALUES (@email_address, @username', @password)"]
insert_ds.insert
```

The error message is

> Sequel::DatabaseError at /
>   PG::Error: ERROR: column "email_address" does not exist LINE 1: ...sers (email_address, username, password) VALUES (@email_addr... ^

which leads me to presume that the parameter was not passed

The full code is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require "rubygems"
require "sequel"
require 'sinatra/sequel'
require 'pg'

DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://my username:my password@ec2-54-243-250-125.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d70h0792oqobc')

get '/' do
  #@users = users.all :order => :id.desc
  #@title = 'All Users'
  erb :index
end

post '/' do
    @email_address = params[:email_address]
    @username = params[:username]
    @password = params[:password]
    insert_ds = DB["INSERT INTO users (email_address, username, password) VALUES (@email_address, @username, @password)"]
    insert_ds.insert
    redirect '/'
end


__END__

@@ layout
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>

@@index
<section id="add">
  <form action="/" method="post">
  <label class="label"> <span>Email Address: </span> </label> <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" />
  <label class="label"> <span>Username: </span> </label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
  <label class="label"> <span>Password: </span> </label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register me!">
  </form>
</section>
```

Very grateful for all help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to interpolate the global variables `@email_address`, `@username`, and `@password` but haven't used the interpolation operator `#`

Your SQL string apears as

```
INSERT INTO users (email_address, username, password) VALUES (@email_address, @username', @password)
```

when (apart from the stray single quote) you mean to have the *values* of those variables appear within the command. You should write instead

```
    insert_ds = DB["INSERT INTO users (email_address, username, password)
                               VALUES (#@email_address, #@username, #@password)"]
```

It is easy to diagnose this by adding

```
puts insert_ds
```

directly after the assignment.

Comment: +1 for correctly identifying the source of the problem, but -1 because directly taking user input to construct SQL statements via string interpolation is exactly the sort of thing that gets websites owned via SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Phrogz: To an extent I agree. But not knowing `Sequel` and how (and whether) to use placeholders I left it as a working hack. Validating user input is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: thank you both contributions, very helpful. I am sorry if it seems so simple. I am coming form PHP background and the adjustment is difficult.

Comment: @user1903663: The mistake is forgiveable. I just don't understand why you couldn't debug it by displaying the contents of `insert_ds` before executing it.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**: Your code wasn't working because you were sending invalid SQL to the database, due to a misunderstanding of how Sequel works (and how Ruby's string interpolation works).

**Details**:
You almost never need to (nor should you) write raw SQL code when using the Sequel library. To use Sequel more appropriately, do this:

```
DB[:users] << {
  email_address: params[:email_address],
  username:      params[:my_username],
  password:      params[:my_password]
}
```

or this:

```
DB[:users].insert( email_address:params[:email_address], … )
```

If you want to store these as instance variables for some reason (you're using them in a view response for the post?) then:

```
@email = params[:email_address]
@user  = params[:username]
@pass  = params[:password]
DB[:users] << { email_address:@email, username:@user, password:@pass }
```

If you really want to write raw SQL, you can use placeholders safely like so:

```
DB[
  'INSERT INTO users (email_address,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?)',
  params[:email_address],
  params[:username],
  params[:password],
]
```

The benefit of this is that it prevents users from performing a [SQL Injection Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on your site, for example by saying that their username is `bob','haha'); drop table users; select('`. *(Think about what happens if you put that into a normal `INSERT` statement between two `'` characters.)*

Since your form parameters match your column names, you can even use a custom function for [slicing your hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652976/slicing-params-hash-for-specific-values) to make this even easier, e.g.

```
DB[:users] << params.slice(:email_address,:username,:password)
```

Read the [Sequel Documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) (e.g. the [Cheat Sheet](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html)) for more information on how to properly use it.

**For the Future**:

Your problem was unrelated to Sinatra or parameters, but simply how you were incorrectly using Sequel. For the future, to test if you *are* getting your parameters, you can do:

```
p params
```

and look at your console (I assume you are developing locally?) or else use whatever logging capabilities Heroku gives you if you are developing live on the server (*shudder*). Alternatively, you can even do:

```
post '/' do
  params.inspect
end
```

and you will see, when you post the form, exactly what is in the `params` hash. Then you won't apply blame and investigation to the wrong area.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Perhaps because of a perceived "RTFM" style part in the middle?

Comment: @user1903663 You're welcome. Note that if you feel that this has fully answered your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153741) by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for an amazingly full analysis of my errors and the proposed solutions, I am very grateful. I note particularly what you say about "sql injection". I have learnt something important here.